# Netbeans change Diff-view border color

Tags: user-interface, netbeans

Can someone guide me to the right item under Fonts&Colors to change the border color of Diff-view items to white. And if there isn't an option there, can it be changed somewhere under the hood?

Example of the borders:

[image: Example of the borders]

Answer (score 0):

This color is set by look and feel property 'ScrollPane.border'. I can think of 3 options.

A: create netbeans plugin to modify this property (however this would set the color to all scrollpanes).

B: Download source of diff module, modify it and install as plugin.

C: Switch netbeans look and feel (Tools|Options|Appearance|Look and Feel)

I would stick with current state, because it is not easy to change.